# Integrate $\int\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$ using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus

Integrate $\int\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \, dx$ using trigonometric substitution

Ok, so it's been a really long time since I've done a problem like this but after doing a little bit o studying, this is how far I've gotten.

$$\int\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx$$

Focusing on the denominator and using a triangle, I found that $\sin\theta=\frac{x}{a}$, therefore $x=a\sin\theta$ and $dx=a\cos\theta \, d\theta$

Plugging this into the given problem, I got $\int\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\, dx$ ${}= \int\frac{a^4 \sin^4\theta}{a\cos\theta}\cdot a\cos\theta \, d \theta $= $a^4\int (\sin^4 \theta ) \, d \theta$

Since $\sin^2\theta=\frac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}$, I can say

$$a^4\int (\sin^4 \theta \,d \theta =a^4\int\frac{1-2\cos2\theta+\cos^22\theta}{4}\,)d\theta$$ Pulling out the 4 from the denominator and substituting $\cos^22\theta=1-\sin^22\theta$, I get

$$\frac{a^4}{4} \int({1-2\cos2\theta+1-\sin^22\theta})\, d\theta=\frac{a^4}{4}\int({2-2\cos2\theta-\sin^22\theta}) \, d\theta$$

Substituting $\sin^22\theta for \frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2}$ gets me

$$\frac{a^4}{4}\int(2-2\cos2\theta-\frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2})d\theta=\frac{a^4}{8}\int(4-4\cos2\theta-1+\cos4\theta) \, d\theta=\frac{a^4}{8}\int(3-4 \cos2\theta + \cos4\theta)\, d\theta$$

$$=\frac{a^4}{8}[3\theta-\frac{4\sin2\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin4\theta}{4}]+C$$

From here, there are some substitutions that we must do.

We know that $sin\theta=\frac{x}{a}$ So, $\theta=sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$

Also, $sin2\theta=2sin\theta cos\theta$=$2*\frac{x}{a}*\frac{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{a}$ and $sin4\theta=4cos^3\theta sin\theta-4sin^3\theta cos\theta=4*({\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}})^3*\frac{x}{a}-4*(\frac{x}{a})^3*\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}$

Substituting this gives,

$\frac{a^4}{8}[3sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}-\frac{8x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2}+\frac{4x(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}^3}{a^2}-\frac{4x^3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2}]+C$

And then finally, $\frac{3a^4}{8}sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}-\frac{a^2x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{2}+\frac{a^2x(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}^3}{2}-\frac{ax^3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{2}]+C$

Is this correct? Please critique, comment, and help clarify. I really need to understand this problem.

Comment: You can derive the formulas for double and quadruple angle by doing the addition formulas twice and then derive the double angle formula using this method. For the quadruple angle, use the double angle formula on the double angle formula. You can also find that:
$$\mathrm{sin(x)=y\implies sin(kx)=sin\left(ksin^{-1}(y)\right)}$$

Comment: I don't think the $d\theta$ term should come in the final answer.

Comment: @Aditya no, it shouldnt. I would have to substitute back in for it, like I did in the beginning of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo, though it was not critical:
$$sin2\theta=2sin\theta cos\theta=2*\frac{x}{a}*\frac{\sqrt{\color{red}x^2-\color{red}a^2}}{a} \text{ must be } \\
\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta \cos\theta=2*\frac{x}{a}*\frac{\sqrt{\color{red}a^2-\color{red}x^2}}{a}$$

You made some minor errors while substituting:
$$\frac{a^4}{8}[3sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}-\frac{\color{red}8x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2}+\frac{\color{red}4x(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}^3}{a^\color{red}2}-\frac{\color{red}4x^3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^\color{red}2}]+C \text{ must be}\\
\frac{a^4}{8}[3\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}-\frac{\color{red}4x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2}+\frac{x(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\color{red})^3}{a^\color{red}4}-\frac{x^3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^\color{red}4}]+C=\\
\frac{3a^4}{8}\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}-\frac{xa^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{2}+\frac{x(a^2-x^2)\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{8}-\frac{x^3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{8}+C=\\
\frac{3a^4}{8}\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{a}-\frac{3xa^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{8}-\frac{x^3\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{4}+C$$

Comment: Maybe you can use `\sin` and `\cos` instead of `sin` and `cos`?

Comment: soulpless, Done, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can expand $\sin(4\theta)$ and $\sin(2\theta)$ using trigonometric identities

$\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha), \cos(2\alpha)= \cos^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(\alpha)$.

Therefore $$\sin(4\theta)= 2\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta) = 2\cdot 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cdot (\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)) =  4\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta) - 4\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(1-\sin^2(\theta)) - 4\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-4\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta) - 4\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-8\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$ should be obvious as well (keeping the power of $\cos$ to $1$ so you don't have to play with powers of square roots).

Using the answer you arrived at $$\frac{3a^4}{8}\theta - \frac{a^4}{4}\sin(2\theta)+\frac{a^4}{8}\frac{\sin(4\theta)}{4} +C\Longrightarrow \\ \frac{3a^4}{8}\theta - \frac{a^4}{4}\left(2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\right)+\frac{a^4}{8}\frac{4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-8\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{4} +C\Longrightarrow \\
\frac{3a^4}{8}\theta - \frac{a^4}{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{a^4}{8}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\frac{a^4}{8}\left(2\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)\right)+C \Longrightarrow \\
\frac{3a^4}{8}\theta - \frac{3a^4}{8}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\frac{a^4}{4}\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)+C$$ since $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8} = -\frac{3}{8}$.

It's a matter of substituting $\sin(\theta) = \frac{x}{a}$, $\theta =\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$ and $\cos(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}$ after, which I'll leave to you, the MathJax in your work could use some editing.

---

In my Stewart Calculus textbook (7th edition) Integration by Parts comes before Trigonometric Substitution.

Since you have $\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta$ where the power of sine is only 4 it shouldn't be too lengthy to do the integration by parts. *I would explain that you could use trigonometric substitution, and then integration by parts to solve the integral.*

There is a formula at the back of the text for general integrals of this form:

$$\int \sin^n(u)\:du = -\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}(u)\cos(u)+\frac{n-1}{n}\int\sin^{n-2}(u)\:du.$$

To see how to find this formula consider the formula for integration by parts which is based on the product rule $\frac{d}{dx}[f\cdot g] = f'\cdot g + f \cdot g'$:

$$f\cdot g' = \frac{d}{dx}[f\cdot g] - f' \cdot g$$

integrating both sides

$$\int \color{aqua}{f(x)}\color{red}{g'(x)\:dx} = \color{aqua}{f(x)}\color{lime}{g(x)}-\int \color{lime}{g(x)}\color{orange}{f'(x)\:dx}$$

and letting $\color{aqua}{u} = \color{aqua}{f(x)}$ and $\color{lime}v = \color{lime}{g(x)}$ then $\color{orange}{du} = \color{orange}{f'(x)\:dx}$ and $\color{red}{dv} = \color{red}{g'(x)\:dx}$ to get the much more memorable formula

$$\int \color{aqua}{u}\:\color{red}{dv} = \color{aqua}u\color{lime}v-\int \color{lime}v\:\color{orange}{du}.$$

A way to work with this formula would be to create an array, you'll see shortly, in our case we have $\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta$, so we have to decide how we want to split things up, as in $\int \color{aqua}{\sin^4(\theta)}\cdot \color{red}{d\theta}$ or $\int \color{aqua}{\sin^3(\theta)}\cdot \color{red}{\sin(\theta)\:d\theta}$ or $\int \color{aqua}{\sin^2(\theta)}\cdot \color{red}{\sin^2(\theta)\:d\theta}$ or $\int \color{aqua}{\sin(\theta)}\cdot \color{red}{\sin^3(\theta)\:d\theta}$.

If we choose $\int \color{aqua}{\sin^3(\theta)}\cdot \color{red}{\sin(\theta)\:d\theta}$ then

$$
\begin{array}
\hline
{\color{aqua}u = \sin^3(\theta)} & {\color{lime}v = -\cos(\theta)}   \\
\downarrow_\text{differentiate} & \uparrow_\text{integrate}\\
\color{orange}{du} = 3\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)\:d\theta & {\color{red}{dv} = \sin(\theta)d\theta}
\end{array}
$$

then $$\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta = \int \color{aqua}{\sin^3(\theta)}\cdot \color{red}{\sin(\theta)\:d\theta} = \color{lime}-\color{aqua}{\sin^3(\theta)}\color{lime}{\cos(\theta)} + \color{orange}3\int \color{orange}{\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)}\color{lime}{\cos(\theta)}\: \color{orange}{d\theta} \\=-\sin^3(\theta){\cos(\theta)} + 3\int {\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}\: {d\theta}$$

but $\cos^2(\theta) = 1 - \sin^2(\theta)$ so $\sin^2(\theta)(1-\sin^2(\theta)) = \sin^2(\theta)-\sin^4(\theta)$ and $3\int \sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)\: d\theta = 3\int \sin^2(\theta)\:d\theta-3\int\sin^4(\theta)\: d\theta$:

$$\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta = -\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)+3\int \sin^2(\theta)\:d\theta-3\int\sin^4(\theta)\: d\theta$$

and now we have reduced the problem to an integral we know how to solve $(\int \sin^2(\theta)\:d\theta)$ and we can bring $-3\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta$ to the right because it is equal to a multiple of the integral we're trying to solve:

$$4\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta = -\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)+3\int \sin^2(\theta)\:d\theta.$$

Hence why for $n=4$

$$\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta = -\frac{1}{4}\sin^{3}(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{3}{4}\int\sin^{2}(\theta)\:d\theta$$

and similarly for $n=2$

$$\int \sin^2(\theta)\:d\theta = -\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\theta$$

and together $$\int \sin^4(\theta)\:d\theta = -\frac{1}{4}\sin^{3}(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{3}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\theta\right) \\=-\frac{1}{4}\sin^{3}(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\frac{3}{8}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{3}{8}\theta.$$

Using a right triangle to deduce that if $\sin(\theta)=\frac{x}{a}$ then $\cos(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}}{a}$ and $\theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$

$$-\frac{1}{4}\sin^{3}(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\frac{3}{8}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{3}{8}\theta$$ $$= -\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^3\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}}{a}-\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{x}{a}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}}{a}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$ $$= -\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{x^3}{a^4}\cdot\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}-\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{x}{a^2}\cdot\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

And we only need to multiply by $a^4$ to get the answer:

$$a^4 \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{x^3}{a^4}\cdot\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}-\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{x}{a^2}\cdot\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)+C= \\ -\frac{1}{4}\cdot{x^3}\cdot\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}-\frac{3a^2}{8}\cdot x\cdot\sqrt{a^2 -x^2}+\frac{3a^4}{8}\cdot\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$$

Hope this helps, hopefully the colors aren't too confusing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute $\theta=\arcsin(\frac{x}{a})$, or as you said just find $\sin(4\theta) $ and $\sin (2\theta)$ using the double angle properties and put the values in the final answer.